# Error messages not shown with @mui/x-date-pickers and Formik validation

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, gatsby, formik, mui-x

I am using the **`DatePicker`** component from **`@mui/x-date-pickers`** along with Formik for validation in a React project. However, when I manually change the input to a date in the past, no error message is being shown.
Here is the relevant code:

```
<LocalizationProvider
  adapterLocale={locale}
  dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
>
  <DatePicker
    label={t('test.form.license-expiry-date')}
    id={t('test.form.license-expiry-date')}
    name="dLExpDate"
    value={dayjs(values.dLExpDate)}
    onChange={date => {
      if (date) {
        const newDate = date.toDate();
        const formattedStartDate = format(newDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');

        handleChange('dLExpDate')(formattedStartDate);
        // Set the field as touched
        setFieldTouched('dLExpDate', true, false);

        // Simulate onBlur behavior
        if (!errors.dLExpDate) {
          props.setFieldValue(
            'dLExpDate',
            transformDateString(formattedStartDate)
          );
        }
      } else {
        // Handle the case when the date is deleted
        handleChange('dLExpDate')('');
        setFieldTouched('dLExpDate', true, false);
        props.setFieldValue('dLExpDate', null); // Set to null or handle as needed
      }
    }}
    disablePast="true"
    orientation="portrait"
    error={errors.dLExpDate && touched.dLExpDate}
    helperText={touched.dLExpDate && errors.dLExpDate}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    dLExpDate: null,
  }}
  validationSchema={validator({
    dLExpDate: {
      validatorKey: 'dLExpDate',
      required: true,
    },
  })}
>
  {/* Other form components */}
</Formik>
```

```
dLExpDate: function (t) {
  return Yup.string()
    .oneOfLengths([10], t('test.error.date'))
    .matches(dateRegExp, t('test.error.date'))
    .test('date', 'Invalid date. Must be today or later', function (value) {
      if (!value) {
        return true; // Skip validation if the value is empty
      }
      const selectedDate = new Date(value);
      const currentDate = new Date();
      debugger;
      return selectedDate >= currentDate;
    });
},
```

Despite setting the field as touched and having the correct conditions for displaying errors (**`error={errors.dLExpDate && touched.dLExpDate}`**), the error messages are not being shown.

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put error and helperText inside slotProps textField

```
<DatePicker
    label={t('test.form.license-expiry-date')}
    id={t('test.form.license-expiry-date')}
    name="dLExpDate"
    value={dayjs(values.dLExpDate)}
    onChange={date => {
      if (date) {
        const newDate = date.toDate();
        const formattedStartDate = format(newDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');

        handleChange('dLExpDate')(formattedStartDate);
        // Set the field as touched
        setFieldTouched('dLExpDate', true, false);

        // Simulate onBlur behavior
        if (!errors.dLExpDate) {
          props.setFieldValue(
            'dLExpDate',
            transformDateString(formattedStartDate)
          );
        }
      } else {
        // Handle the case when the date is deleted
        handleChange('dLExpDate')('');
        setFieldTouched('dLExpDate', true, false);
        props.setFieldValue('dLExpDate', null); // Set to null or handle as needed
      }
    }}
    disablePast="true"
    orientation="portrait"
    slotProps={{
      textField: {
        error: Boolean(errors.dLExpDate && touched.dLExpDate),
        helperText: Boolean(touched.dLExpDate && errors.dLExpDate),
      },
    }}
  />
```